# Why does $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \beta\right) = \frac{t}{s}$ imply that $\tan\beta = \frac{s}{t}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have been preparing for the SAT on KhanAcademy. For one of the trigonometry problems, the following conversion is made:

$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} − \beta\right)= \frac{t}{s}$$

$$\tan(\beta) = \frac{s}{t}$$

There is no explanation for how this change works. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $$\tan(\pi/2-\beta)=\frac{\sin(\pi/2-\beta)}{\cos(\pi/2-\beta)}=\frac{\cos\beta}{\sin\beta}=\frac{1}{\tan\beta}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan (90^\circ - x) \equiv \cot x = \frac{1}{\tan x}$$